# Difference between "didn't" and "hadn't"

Tags: past-tense, auxiliary-verbs, verb-forms, subjunctives

Is *didn't* or *hadn't* correct below?  What is the difference?

> Please do not dock my pay as I was in the office but **didn't** brought my ID card.

or

> Please do not dock my pay as I was in the office but **hadn't** brought my ID card.

Comment: If you are going to use "didn't" then you should say "didn't bring my ID card".
More generally, the sentence as a whole could do with some tweaks to improve understandability. I think what you are trying to say is something like: "Please don't consider docking my pay, as I was in the office, but did not have my ID card with me."

Comment: @Graham probably something more like "Please consider not docking my pay, as I was in the office but did not have my ID card".

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand the whole sentences despite correcting the grammar mistakes. Why does the boss dock your pay for forgetting to bring your ID card? Or you're trying to connote not to dock your pay as you didn't bring your ID card?

Comment: If you're trying to connote not to dock your pay as you didn't bring your ID card, then replacement of "although" with "but" makes the sentence flow better becoming _Please do not dock my pay as I was in the office although I did not bring my ID card."_

Answer (score 5):

*"I didn't bring..."* **The past tense** describes an action which happened in the past.
*" I hadn't brought...* **'The past perfect tense** describes an action which happened before another action in the past, or before a stated time in the past. So in the second sentence you're stressing the fact that you had forgotten to take your ID card before you went to the office, whereas in the first you're just stating that you didn't bring your ID card.
As for your sentence it would be better to say, "Please do not consider docking my pay, as I was in the office, but I dind't have or / I hadn't brought my ID card."
One more thing. When you have a negative or interrogative sentence in the Past Simple remember that the verb is in its affirmative form. e.g. I didn't bring. Did you bring?

Comment: Note that **past simple** besides of describing an action which happened in the past, it also says when happened at a specific time.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on a tense:

1) Past Simple

I *bought* a car. -- I **didn't buy** a car.

I *had* a car some time ago. -- I **didn't have** a car some time ago.

Passive

A car was bought by me. -- A car wasn't bought by me.

2) Past Perfect Tense

Before I passed to a college I had already bought a car. -- Before I passed to a college I **hadn't** already bought a car.

Before I passed to a college I had already had a car. -- Before I passed to a college I hadn't already had a car.

Passive

A car had been bought by me before... -- A car hadn't been bought by me before...

So, the difference between *hadn't* and *didn't* is that they are used in different tenses and have different meaning. In this case the sentence

> Please do not dock my pay as I was in the office but hadn't brought my
>   ID card.

is a correct Past Perfect sentence.